# How to create new field in type id in android

Tags: android

I am creating a Sudoku game, and in its full screen activity I am getting an error from this code:

```
final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

These fields are not created in R.java file, but when I create it it's showing an error.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding in eclipse.

Comment: What does the `error` say?

Comment: there is some mistake in your xml, that is why it is giving errors. Generally if you are unable to find view by id or if the R file is not generating the code for the new views it indicates malformed xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an ID to a View call [`setId(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29).

If you have created the views in a layout file (.xml) then it's better to set the ID's in your xml file with this attribute: `android:id="@+id/yourID"`.

Now you can call `findViewById(R.id.yourID)`.